# Defining the quotient map

Tags: general-topology, definition

In *Introduction to Topological Manifolds* by John Lee the quotient map is defined in the following way

> Let $ q : X \to X/$~ be the natural projection sending each element of $X$ to its equivalence class, then $X/$~ together with the quotient topology induced by $q$ is called the quotient space

where $X$ is a topological space and $X/$~ is the quotient space. My question is that the above definition implies $q(x) = [x]$, hence it seems like $q$ isn't even a function as it may map a single point $x$ to many points in the equivalence class $[x]$

Is there an error in my understanding?

Comment: $q$ doesn't map $x$ to all the points in $[x]$. It maps $x$ to the _single_ element $[x]\in X/\sim$.

Comment: The map $q$ sends an element $x$ to its equivalence class $[x]$, but it is wrong to say that $x$ is sent to every element in $[x]$. The whole point of the quotient map is that if $x\sim y$, then $[x]=[y]$ and so although you can technically say that $q(x)=[x]$ or $q(x)=[y]$, you are in fact saying the same thing.

Comment: The _points_ of $X/{\sim}$ are subsets of $X$.

Comment: Each element of $X$ belongs to exactly **one** equivalence class wich is denoted by $[x]$ (so $x\in[x]$). Every $x\in X$ is sent to the class that $x$ belongs to: i.e. $x\mapsto[x]$. Also be aware that we can have $[x]=[y]$ together with $x\neq y$. In that case the distinct $x,y$ are elements of the same equivalence class.

Comment: @DanielFischer Ohhh so the *points* of $X/$~ are the equivalence classes themselves?

Comment: Yes. $X/{\sim}$ is the set of equivalence classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $x,y$ belong to the same equivalence class then

$$
[x]=[y]
$$

you are free to use the symbol $[x]$ or $[y]$ to represent the same equivalence class.

Your function $q$ will not be multivalued since

$$
q(x)=[x]
$$

$$
q(x)=[y]
$$

but as stated previously $[x]$ and $[y]$ are the same element.

Answer (score 2):

A common way to think of quotient maps is that they take each equivalence class and shrink it to a single point. That single point is the image, under $q()$ of every point that was in the equivalence class.

For a simple, concrete example, consider the function $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ defined by $f(z)=e^{iz}$, and consider its restriction to the line segment $[0,2\pi]$. This maps sends a line segment to a circle, and in doing so, it sends the points $0$ and $2\pi$ to the same point, namely $1$. The equivalence classes of this quotient are singletons for every point in the open interval $(0,2\pi)$, and the two-element equivalence class $\{0,2\pi\}$, which we could call $[0]$ or $[2\pi]$.

We can think of $f$ as a composition of two maps: $f=\iota\circ q$, where $q$ is a purely topological quotient map which sends each point to the singleton consisting of itself, except for the end points, which are "glued" together in a single equivalence class, and $\iota$ is an inclusion map which sticks the resulting circle back into $\mathbb{C}$.

It should be clear that $f(0) = f(2\pi) = 1 =\iota(\{0,2\pi\})$, so both points are sent to a single element of the image, even though you can see that each of those points is mapped to the common destination of two points. Thus, a quotient map is not a "one-to-many" map, which would not be a function, but it is a "many-to-one" map, i.e., a non-injective function.